# Four of a kind from a 3d pack of cards

Tags: probability

I have a $64$-card deck, with $4$ colours - red, green, blue, yellow, $4$ numbers - $1,2,3,4$ and $4$ letters A,B,C,D. So an example card could be yellow2D.

I was attempting to calculate the probability of $4$ of a kind, i.e. $4$ green cards, $4$ $3$'s, etc... having been dealt $k$ cards.

But I got all stuck!

Comment: So, how many ways can you get 4 red cards? how many ways can you get four 3s? how many ways can you get four Bs? How many total deals are there? how should you put all these numbers together?

Comment: That's not enough data, of course, because it is possible to get four red 3s, @GerryMyerson

Comment: @Thomas, you're right; one has to calculate those numbers as well, and then appeal to Inclusion-Exclusion.